# Customization of the total page number

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

How to customize the total page number for all of the frames from the beginning, please?

Comment: Can you be more precise about `"customize"` ?
What do you want ? Change the first number, change the style ? Set numbers from section numbers ?

Comment: I want to set the total that will be displayed in the foot of the frames from the begginning? For example, I want that the total is equal to 20 on all of the frames.

Comment: Could add to your question a minimal complete example showing your problem? If your total page number is shown in all frames it should be the same in all frames. Did you compiled twice?

Comment: @Ignasi, I need just the command line because I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What command line? What are you talking about? Please look at the link Johannes_B suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after `\begin{document}`, use

```
\def\inserttotalframenumber{20}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\def\inserttotalframenumber{20}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I deservedly lack the reputation points.  If you use the `\def\inserttotalframenumber{20}` solution, be aware that the number of the final slide, which is different from what the questioner wanted, gets recorded in the `.aux` file, and this, in turn, gets dumped into the `.nav` file.  Hence if you rerun latex without removing these files (which you might have to, if you have labels or use bibtex), you can get your desired final frame number overwritten by the apparent number from the beamer file.